# Button and ON_MESSAGE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, button, mfc

In gui app there is ON_MESSAGE(id, handler) with hanler's `LRESULT CMainFrame::handler(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` declaration.
Well, visial studio doesn't want to get such handler in ON_COMMAND(). What can I do to use the same hanler in ON_MESSAGE and in ON_COMMAND?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you noticed the handlers need different declarations to work for the ON_MESSAGE and the ON_COMMAND so you can't have the same function for both ON_COMMAND and ON_MESSAGE.
you will have to create one function for each handler and then you can encapsulate your code into another function that is called from the first handlers.

like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyClass, CMyParentClass)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyClass)
    ON_MESSAGE(ID_MY_MESSAGE_ID,OnMyMessage)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_MY_COMMAND_ID,OnMyCommand)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
LRESULT CMyClass::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

   MyEncapsulatedCode();

   return 0;
}
void CMyClass::OnMyCommand()
{
   MyEncapsulatedCode();
}
void CMyClass::MyEncapsulatedCode()
{
    //do stuff
}
```